# Everything turns black in Netrender mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, network

I used Cycles for rendering my scene, and I wanted to render my animation through network render. When I switch from cycles to network render, all of my objects turn black (3D view, no matter whether it's solid/texture/material view). What am I missing? And yes, I've packed everything into .blend files.

Comment: What version of Blender are you using?  In 2.77 I can't reproduce it, but I remember it happening in the past (in which renders still worked fine).

Answer (score 2):

If you change your render engine from Cycles to Network render, make sure you specify what render engine you would like to use in the network render settings.

[image]

The Blackness may be becase you used the blender internal render engine to render the scene. Since cycle nodes get ignored by this engine its not working properly. -> everything may be black. Because there may be no light.